# Bell-carrying Bamboo?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In "Animal Crossing: New Leaf," I am growing a bamboo shoot that I bought from the emporium. I am curious to know: can bells be produced in these plants? Can ANYTHING be produced by these plants?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bamboo shoots grow to become [**bamboo**](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Bamboo).

They carry **no fruit** (and certainly **not bells**), but they do work well for decoration purposes and reproduce quite quickly. When bamboo has grown, it will periodically **create new shoots** that get **buried around it**. These shoots will plant themselves if left unattended, but can also be **sold** or used as **food**.